# Ignorance is bliss but . . . .?

Tags: phrase-requests, proverb-requests

I am looking for a phrase which completes the sentence with following meaning.

> Ignorance is bliss but **its consequence is disastrous.**

I came up with *its consequence is disastrous*.

Is there any known phrase or proverb close to this meaning?

Comment: Can't think of a well-known one, so won't answer, but if extending the "ignorance is bliss" I'd perhaps turn it so that its the bliss that gets blamed; "ignorance is bliss, but bliss can be dangerous" or some such.

Comment: Yours and @JonHanna 's are both very good! You could also consider combining it with other "ignorance" quotes, like "... but it 's [still] not a virtue." or "... but it [still] excuses no one/not."

Comment: *Ignorance of the law is no excuse* is an actual idiomatic phrase.

Comment: @Clare OH wow. You just connected things in my head and I'm totally going to use "ignorance of the law isn't bliss" or something similar in a political context soon. Thanks!

Comment: @Clare it's also a fact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Thomas Gray's poem, Ode on a Distant Prospect of Eton College (1742)

the actual full phrase...

> "—where ignorance is bliss,
>               'Tis folly to be wise."  [(Thomas Grey Archive)](http://www.thomasgray.org/cgi-bin/display.cgi?text=odec)

Many compare this with the phrase:   "What you don't know can't hurt you"

I prefer Ricky Gervais' take:

> "Ignorance is bliss.  But only for the ignorant."

Comment: _But only for the ignorant._ That's a good one. What should we call it ? A satire ?